# Como fazer um menu que ao clicar abre outra div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

EXEMPLO: eu quero criar um menu que terá quatro links, e cada link abre uma determinada div com conteudos diferentes em cada div. tipo o desse site aqui http://www.futebol.com/ a parte que tem TODOS / FINALIZADOS / AO VIVO / PROXIMOS.

OBS: Desculpem qualquer coisa pois estou aprendendo ainda!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui tem um exemplo que como fazer, existem várias maneiras.

```js
$('.seccao:gt(0)').hide(); // para começar vamos esconder todas as seccoes excepto a primeira 
$('.menu-item').on('click', function() { // quando clicamos num item do menu
  $('.seccao').hide(); // escondemos todas
  var seccao = $(this).data('open'); // aqui vamos obter o id da seccao a aparecer ex: '#todos'
  $(seccao).show(); // e finalmente mostramos a seccao que tem o mesmo id do atributo data-open do item em que clicamos
});
```

```css
.seccao {
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-item" data-open="#todos">
  TODOS
</div>
<div class="menu-item" data-open="#finalizados">
  FINALIZADOS
</div>
<div class="menu-item" data-open="#aovivo">
  AO VIVO
</div>
<div class="menu-item" data-open="#proximos">
  PROXIMOS.
</div>

<div id="master">
  <div class="seccao" id="todos">
    TODOS OS JOGOS APARECEM AQUI
  </div>
  <div class="seccao" id="finalizados">
    TODOS OS JOGOS finalizados APARECEM AQUI
  </div>
  <div class="seccao" id="aovivo">
    TODOS OS JOGOS AO VIVO APARECEM AQUI
  </div>
  <div class="seccao" id="proximos">
    TODOS OS JOGOS PROXIMOS APARECEM AQUI
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso queira ver o exemplo ao vivo: http://codepen.io/leofontes/pen/aBmKzG

Aqui vai um Codepen com um exemplo bem básico, só pra você ter uma ideia do caminho, mas recomendo entender o que está acontecendo e tentar fazer um você mesmo:

HTML

```
<header>
  <a href="#" id="linkUm">Menu1</a>
  <a href="#" id="linkDois">Menu2</a>
  <a href="#" id="linkTres">Menu3</a>
  <a href="#" id="linkQuatro">Menu4</a>
</header>

<div id="um"></div>
<div id="dois"></div>
<div id="tres"></div>
<div id="quatro"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#um {
  background-color: red;
}

#dois {
  background-color: blue;
}

#tres {
  background-color: purple;
}

#quatro {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('#linkUm').click(function() {
  $('#um').fadeIn();
});

$('#linkDois').click(function() {
  $('#dois').fadeIn();
});

$('#linkTres').click(function() {
  $('#tres').fadeIn();
});

$('#linkQuatro').click(function() {
  $('#quatro').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: pow muito obrigado man era isso mesmo que eu tava procurando